# Is SHAPE_Area a numerical or BLOB form of data classification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm having a hard time understanding the information that can be stored in a BLOB.

It's pretty self-evident that SHAPE_Area *has* a numerical value, but is the actual classification a BLOB or Number?

Answer (score 0):

From the Layer Properties of this file geodatabase feature class you can see that SHAPE_Area is of data type Double.  It is not stored as a BLOB.

[image]

If you are referring to a geometry when you say blob here, then for geodatabases, but not shapefiles, the area is dynamically updated when the geometry is edited.

Comment: The value is only dynamic when it's a property of the data source. And it's only represented in the units of the source's coordinate reference (e.g., as square degrees in a GCS). If the shapefile is loaded into another format, or even a different shapefile, and the conversion makes the dynamic field a permanent in a new table, then it will no longer be dynamic.